# interval must contain two elements

Tags: r

I'm trying to subselect in a dataframe :

```
[ time %bw% '2020-08-06' ]
```

and the function gives me the following error :

```
Error in time %bw% "2020-08-06" : interval must contain two elements
```

this is the df :

```
> head(GBPUSD_mt5_ticks)

> A tibble: 6 x 5

>  time                  bid   ask price volume
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>

> 1 2020-08-05 01:00:00  1.31  1.31  1.31      3

> 2 2020-08-05 01:00:00  1.31  1.31  1.31      3

> 3 2020-08-05 01:00:00  1.31  1.31  1.31      4

> 4 2020-08-05 01:00:00  1.31  1.31  1.31      1

> 5 2020-08-05 01:00:00  1.31  1.31  1.31      3

> 6 2020-08-05 01:00:01  1.31  1.31  1.31      3
```

I would like to select an interval, already tried with data on the same structure and things had gone well, tried to put date and time after %bw% and same problem, can someone more experienced explain me please?

If you can teach me how to sellect a multiple day interval to would be great

Best Regards

Comment: Can you specify the packages used

Comment: @r2evans, I would also have had the same thoughts, but`%bw%` [allows a single date](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/QuantTools/versions/0.5.7.1/topics/bw), the reason for the error was more basic, see anwer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can be reproduced:

```
library(quantTools)

data <- tibble::tibble(time = Sys.time())
data[time %bw% '2020-08-06']
Error in time %bw% "2020-08-06" : interval must contain two elements
```

This is due to the fact that `time` is a function and not the `time` column.

Try:

```
data[data$time %bw% '2020-08-06']
```

The reason for having an error in this case is that you use a `tibble`.

This would work with a `data.table`, as in `%bw%` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/QuantTools/versions/0.5.7.1/topics/bw):

```
data(ticks)
class(ticks)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

ticks[time %bw% '2020-08-06']
Empty data.table (0 rows and 1 cols): time
```